# Hover style for labels in legend

Tags: highcharts

How to set hover style for labels in legend?

If it is possible to set `cursor: default` on hovering on "Tokyo", "New York", "Berlin", "London" labels in this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ and also prevent changing colors to black or set another color for hovered label?

I've disabled clicking on legend labels by adding this property:

```
plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick = function() {
    return false;
}
```

But now it looks strange that cursor is pointer and labels colors are changing on hover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define it in itemHoverStyle

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemHoverStyle